# Area (or volume) of polygon inscribing a distribution of points/Finding vertices of distribution

Tags: area

I am trying to compute the (maximum) area/volume of a 2D/3D distribution of points. However, I'm struggling to define the outliar points in such distributions without resorting to very bad spaghetti code that will be very inefficient.

So given a 2D distribution of points, is there a simple way to find the vertices? I think that this is probably the real mathematical question, how to find those vertices.  And also can the solution be extended to 3D?

[Area of distribution of points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2atlk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind, I found the answer. Apparently the issue is finding a convex hull/envelope. And there are solutions in python already for N-Dimensions.